# jquery javascript onclick SlideDown panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here the code on bootsnipp: http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/2pvGr

I am trying to link an element of the navigation bar, with a panel. I would like to have the following functionality:

When the element on the navbar with id 'xxx' is clicked, then the panel with the id 'yyy' gets uncollapsed (slideDown())

I am somehow not getting it..

(#osPartner-navbar) is the id of the button on a dropdown in the navigation bar.

You can check the updated JavaScript...

Anyone an idea, how to get this done?

PS: Another small detail.. I would like that the initial position of the panels is "slided-up". So that when I click on the parent panel, and it slides down, both child panels are slided up (closed), and the user has to click on them to get slided down. It would be nice to have that as plus, if someone has a solution for that as well.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
var $this = (document).getElementById('osPartnerUebersicht');
```

with

```
var $this = $('#osPartnerUebersicht');
```

`hasClass` is a jQuery function, so you need the jQuery object.

`getElementById` will return the dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but your JS had few errors I noticed but you have not given full html needed for anyone to help properly but have a look at this:

New:

`instead of using $(document).on use $("#osPartner").on("click", func..)`

```
$("#osPartner").on("click",  function(){
    var $this = $("#osPartnerUebersicht"); // Changed like BenG stated before I posted this.
    console.log($this);
    console.log($this.children[0]); 
    console.log($this.children[1]);

    if ($this.hasClass("panel-primary")) {
        console.log("I do!");
    }
});
```

Here is JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/o8yqpefv/

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById('contents'); //returns a HTML DOM Object

 var contents = $('#contents');  //returns a jQuery Object
```

In jQuery, to get the same result as document.getElementById, you can access the jQuery Object and get the first element in the object (Remember JavaScript objects act similar to associative arrays).

```
var contents = $('#contents')[0]; //returns a HTML DOM Object
```

So you need to use below

```
var $this = $('#osPartnerUebersicht');
```